# Show that the integral $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$ is divergent

Tags: calculus

I have some trouble with this integral. Actually, I know when the interval ranges from 1 to $\infty$, this integral is convergent. But the difficulty I have encountered is how to show the divergence where the case of interval ranges from 0 to 1.

Comment: The indefinite integral is equal to $-\mathrm{arctanh}(\sqrt{1+x^2})$.

Comment: Trigonometrical substitution! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $x=\tan t$,
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \csc t dt =\ln(\tan(x/2))_{0}^{\pi/2}=0-\ln 0=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor expansion around $x=0$ $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ This is more than sufficient.

Still faster, using equivalents, if $x$ is small then $x^2\ll 1$ and
$$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sim \frac 1x$$